# Android List view: Array from web service

Tags: java, android

I am trying to populate a list view in android from an array in a web service I keep getting an error. Here is my Code. in the log cat file i get an error : Can't open file for reading.

```
ListView tv;

public LocationFragment(){}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_location, container, false);
    getView().findViewById(R.id.listView1);


    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME); 

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);


    HttpTransportSE ht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    try {
        ht.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        View response = (View)envelope.getResponse();
        tv.setEmptyView(response);


    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    return rootView;
}


}
```

Comment: Can we see the entire relevant stacktrace and can you point out to which line it's complaining about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not interrupt the main thread of application and you should use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) while you are making a web request.

Comment: I'm new to Android I'm not sure what Async is.

Comment: @user3267471 AsyncTask allows you to do your process (it can be a web request or a function). By the help of AsynTask the main thread of your application does not interrupted and you can complete your process in background with a thread.